# Jquery Autocomplete not to close on click of a button inside the item list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a particular design feature on page I am making, that involves jQuery autocomplete to have buttons next to the search list. I can bind and successfully run events by clicking those buttons. Problem is I don't want the menu to close or the option selected when I click the button. Here is my code.

> ```
> function autocomplete () {
>  $(".header-search-box").autocomplete({
>     source: function(req,res) {
>         $.ajax({
>             url: "/localhost:3000/autocomplete/"+req.term,
>             dataType: "jsonp",
>             type: "GET",
>             data: {
>                 search: req.term
>             },
>             success: function(data) {
>                 res(data)
>             },
>             error: function(xhr) {
>                 alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + xhr.statusText);
>             }
>         });
>     },
>     select: function(event, ui) {
>     }
> }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul,item){
>     return $("<li>")
>     .append("<div class='entry'><a href='/details/"+item._id+"'><img src='"+item.thumbUri+"' height='64' width='26'></img><div class='details'><div class='make'>"+item.make+"</div><div class='model'>"+item.model+"</div></div></a><div class='add-interest'><button  class='{{#liked}}trash{{/liked}}{{^liked}}like{{/liked}}'><i class='fa {{icon}}'></i></button></div></div>")
>     .appendTo(ul);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Any help would be appreciated

**Edit:1**
http://jsfiddle.net/uhLh7/1/ fiddle link to simplified version of the code.
**Edit:2** 
 I am on jquery UI version 1.11.0 and using jquery directly from google cdn. can't find the versions in jsfiddle...

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: @RahulGupta Sorry but I am struggling with the fiddle...

Comment: I have edited you fiddle link to an improved working demo. Please describe now where does the problem lies

Comment: Thanks, looks nicer, So the problem is I want the alert to display as it is doing now, but dont want the item select drop-down to close. I hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind on 'mousedown' event. Here code from your jsfiddle with my changes

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('mousedown', '.add-interest button', function () {
      alert("Sorry, I couldn't bring the object names");
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cancel the button-click event propagation, but **not the event itself**. This will execute the default button click event but will stop the autocomplete from closing.
On getting the data, in ajax's success event:

```
success: function(data) {
    res(data); // Your data handling here
    $('.add-interest button').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation(); // Stop further bubbling of this click event
    });
},
```

Comment: Where will this code go? when I click the button the normal button action performs but the Autocomplete select is also triggered, will this go into my function called autocomplete?

Comment: Hmmm... It doesn't close but nothing is being carried forward either... The function that the button invokes is not being triggered....

Comment: Yes, I suppose it might be possible to prevent trigger of button event but preventing autocomplete close is difficult because for that you have to unbind its `blur` event.

Comment: @j809 I need the button event to follow through, it is the clicking on the button which is inside the menu that appears causes it to close the items menu there and then....

Comment: @j809 lol that was the first thing I did when I got to know that the button click event is not triggered and the autocomplete is following through... it didn't make any difference, same results as before the code was added.